# Does file history allow reconnecting to an old backup and just continue on from there later on like Time Machine?

Tags: windows-10, backup, file-history

I just reinstalled Windows 10 and I wanted to reconnect to my old file history backup on the network share (I don't plan to restore immediately, but I would like it to start backing up and sort of continue from where I left off).

Is it possible?  I can't seem to get around it and the event logs show this

> Unable to start a backup cycle for configuration C:\Users\trajano\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\FileHistory\Configuration\Config

Answer (score 0):

I see the exact same thing, trying to move a physical file history drive to a new machine. Eventually I gave up and just started a new file history, keeping the old one around in case I ever need to manually look through it to find a version of a file.

It is pretty depressing that it doesn't work. I went through a few reinstalls of windows trying different options with respect to file history before I gave up.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible with following instructions at

- https://www.glasswire.com/blog/2022/08/24/moving-your-file-history-to-a-new-computer-by-chris-taylor/
- https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-correctly-use-file-history-to-transfer-data-files-to-a-new-windows-10-installation/

When configuring File History for the first time on your new computer, you have to provide your storage so that to gain access to complete history.